# Python Magic number guesser

Tags: python, list

I am trying to remove numbers from a list until there is only one item left. I am having trouble with my for loop. It keeps giving the error stating:

```
  File "C:/Users/kramsey/Desktop/Python/NumberGuesser2.py", line 28, in <module>
    list.remove(B)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Code:

```
B = random.choice(list)

if ready == "ok":
    lessthan = input("is your number less than {}".format(B)).strip().lower()
    if lessthan == "yes":
        for numbers in list:
            B = int(B+1)
            list.remove(B)
        print(list)
```

I want it to delete the numbers that are not less than the `random.choice(list)` without printing an error to the user once it hits an integer that isn't in the list.

It always tells the user that `list.remove(x) not in list` and doesn't continue through my for loop.

Comment: HOLY COW. DO NOT USE THE NAME `list`!

Comment: Read up on "reserved words in python".

Answer (score 0):

Let us simplify your problem to having a list (appropriately named `l`):

```
l = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9]
```

and a random number (for simplicity's sake, we we'll just set this to `5`):

```
B = 5
```

Now, we can't iterate over `l` and remove items from `l` as this will lead us into problems (as you have seen with that error). So the best way to do this is re-define `l` as a new list that is made with a `list-comprehension`.

```
l = [i for i in l if i > B]
```

and that will leave `l` as:

```
[6, 7, 9]
```

---

This is the *right* way to do what you want and hopefully you can incorporate this into your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list is consisted of sorted numbers, you would have to do something like that:

```
if lessthan == 'yes':
    index = len(list) - 1
    while list[index] >= B:
        list.remove(list[index])
        index -= 1
    print(list)
```

Bear in mind, that you if you are going to alter the list you are iterating over by removing/deleting elements, you should iter backwards(from the end of list to the beginning). Otherwise, you could skip over some elements by deleting an element in the middle of the list.

Comment: I have researched more thoroughly how to use, and what List Comprehensions are. Thanks Jow Iddon!  but now have more issues with indents and "invalid syntax"